# How to handle different input type and single output type in a single function in android kotlin

Tags: android, input, design-patterns

I have two enum classes and data class as below :

NamesEnum.kt

```
enum class NamesEnum(
    val option : String
) {
    AAkASH("Aakash Gupta"),
    ADITI("Aditi Deshpande")
}
```

StateEnum.kt

```
enum class StateEnum(
    val option : String
) {
    KAR("Karnataka"),
    MAH("Maharashtra")
}
```

StudentData.kt

```
data class StudentData(
    var student1: String = "",
    var student2: String = "",
    var state1: String = "",
    var state2: String = "",
   
){
    companion object{
        private var EMPTY_OBJECT: StudentData? = null
        fun getInstance(): StudentData? {
            if (EMPTY_OBJECT == null) EMPTY_OBJECT = StudentData()
            return EMPTY_OBJECT
        }
        fun clearReference(){
            EMPTY_OBJECT = null
        }
    }
}
```

I have to go through each enum classes and update the data in the data class:

```
fun updateData() : List<String>
{
  val list = NamesEnum.values()
        val nameList = ArrayList<String>()
        for (item in list){
            nameList.add(item.option)
        }
        return optionList
}
```

I want the same functionality as in updateData() function but without repeating the logic for every Enum class.
Which design pattern do I have to choose to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You use list of strings instead of enums , and store that lists directly into your data class

```
val namesList : List<String> = listOf("Aakash","Aditi")
val statesList : List<String> = listOf("Karnataka","Maharshtra")

data class StudentData(
    val students: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val states: List<String> = emptyList(),
 
){
    companion object{
        private var EMPTY_OBJECT: StudentData? = null
        fun getInstance(): StudentData? {
            if (EMPTY_OBJECT == null) EMPTY_OBJECT = StudentData()
            return EMPTY_OBJECT
        }
        fun clearReference(){
            EMPTY_OBJECT = null
        }
    }
}




fun updateData(students:List<String>,states:List<String>) : StudentData
{
       
        return StudentData(students,sates)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I do not want to keep the strings in a list, I want them in as Enumerations as I have many such Enumerations to be handled for a single opertaion